# Getting an exception while calling a method of an activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have `class A`,`class B` which extends `Activity`. In `Activity B`, I have created a method, `fillVariable`, as shown below, but when I am calling this method from `Activity A` I am getting `nullPointerException`.

**A activity:**

```
public class A extends Activity{

    B b;

    public void onCreate(Bundle sc){
        setContentView(R.layout.first);
        b = new B();
        b.fillVariable();
    }
}
```

**B Activity:**

```
public class B extends Activity{

    Resources res;

    public void onCreate(Bundle sc){
    }

    public void fillVariable() {
        res = this.getResources();
        String temp = res.getString(R.string.myString);
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot initialise an activity like b = new B();

Comment: then what is the procedure to call fillVariable.

Comment: put the code of fillVariable() into class A. it also get the same result which you trying to get from class B.

Comment: yes V.J but it can be possible that , all function should be hold in b and use for global purpose. its not valid. i also try this but did't get.

Comment: yes chintan this is my global method and i have to use this in different activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass `this` in your A class, like `b = new B(this);`, because you are calling the next activity so they need the context of the activity.

Now **create** the context in class B, like `Context ctx`.

Now define your `class b Constructor` in file b, like:

```
public B(A obj) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.ctx = obj;
}
```

And use the resource using the context obj in any function, like:

```
public String temp;
temp = ctx.getString(R.string.me);
```

It's running. Enjoy...